# What feat should I get for 7th level Rogue Fence/Rich Hoodlum

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue

My Pathfinder rogue has gained 7th level and I really went random on advancement (no research), but I can have a badass sneak attack. My character name is Calico Abacus and he has race traits of *mathematical prodigy* and *dirty fighter*. He was raised by a rug merchant connected to the rug mafia, which employs child labor and slavery to make their goods. As a youth, Calico rebelled and joined an upper-class youth gang and began work on the black market as a fence. He would intimidate as well as deceive his clients. After a contract was put on his head, he was moved to a safehouse to learn discipline with the thieves' guild, "The Order of the Broken Blade," by his father, who could no longer tolerate the bad reputation Abacus was bringing to the family name.

Abacus is a rogue that excels At unarmed combat and is an excellent mathematician(at least he thinks so), as matches the name he was given by his estranged father. Abacus is very good at getting the deal done and is willing to take chances. (more story to come as I edit)

Abacus needs to stack his feats to accumulate the most bonuses on sneak attack, and I believe that will be in his to-hit bonuses.

Here are his stats and feats:

#### Abilities

- Str 14
- Dex 14
- Con 14
- Int 11
- Wis 16
- Cha 11

Rogue 7th level
70 HP

#### Race traits

- Mathematical prodigy
- Dirty Fighter

#### Basic rogue talents

- Evasion
- Uncanny dodge
- Trap sense
- Trap finding
- Surprise attack

#### Feats

- Persuasive
- Improved initiative
- 2 weapon fighting
- Scorpion style
- Improved unarmed strike

He also has night vision and damage resistance due to an encounter with a being named Prometheon as per my DM that I found running blindingly without light in aqueducts beneath the city of Azimuth.

What I would like is help to define my character and use the best stackable feats as I play alongside a philosophy PHD who loves to min-max and argue.

I have one feat to choose now. I know I have made a couple poor choices in my character advancement. All help greatly appreciated. What is my Silver Bullet?!

Comment: Ok I am narrowing down ( since you guys are going to make me decide like my DM) enforcer lights up

Comment: [RPG General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) also in the links up top

Comment: That chat room is dead ,do you think it would be good to get extra rogue talent weapon training then I get weapon focus early

Answer (score 0):

I think I have made my decision to help Abacus the Rogue to maximize his sneak attack , I think Combat Reflexes as it fits with 2 weapon fighting, will be my choice, as it also stacks with all other to hit feats, will be Abacus's best choice for survival at 7th level as it adds a extra attacks and attacks of opportunity , all the others are 6 base attack bonus which I cannot get right now.

Comment: I am not yet decided on the feats, he will be trying to make a name for himself , as that is the adventure, to join a family with a name and combat is how they decide. However I did notice in advanced combat the " combat perform feats